# Entity framwork (code-first) many-to-many LINQ query formation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework code-first suppose I have classes:

```
class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Houses = new List<House>();
    }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<House> Houses { get; set; }
}

public House
{
    public Guid HouseId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a context where only one entity is exposed. I then map them with a many-to-many relationship.

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
         .HasMany(p => p.Houses)
         .WithMany()
         .Map(m =>
         {
             m.ToTable("PeopleHouses");
             m.MapLeftKey("PersonId");
             m.MapRightKey("HouseId");
         }
    }
}
```

When run Entity Framework creates the join table.

My question is how to create a LINQ query to retrieve houses belonging to a single person? (using PersonId)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see your problem... there's a navigation property for it.

```
var houses = People.First(n => /* select your person */).Houses;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var houses = Peoples.Where(p => p.PersonId == YourPersonIdHere).Select(p => p.Houses);
```